# Is it possible in git to stash removing a file from the index?

Tags: git, git-stash

I want to do:

```
git rm --cached file.autogenerated.txt
git stash -m "untrack file.autogenerated.txt"
```

The stash is created but it doesn't seem to have anything in the stash - just 0 files changes, 0 insertions, 0 deletions. And applying this stash has no effect.

I also tried:

```
git rm --cached file.autogenerated.txt
git stash --include-untracked -m "untrack file.autogenerated.txt"
```

But likewise this had no effect.

Is there any way to stash a removal of a file from the index?

Comment: What's the purpose?

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to have anything in the stash - just 0 files changes, 0 insertions, 0 deletions" I think you're misunderstanding what a stash is. It's a commit. A commit is not changes; it's a snapshot of your entire project.

Comment: "And applying this stash has no effect." I rather think that would depend on what you apply it to, don't you? However, as it is entirely unstated what you are trying or expecting to accomplish, no more can be said. What "effect" do you want?

Comment: By how `git stash`'s `--index` option is documented, I'm guessing it doesn't try to apply index changes by default. You can try passing that to `pop` or `apply` and see if that works.

Comment: I just tested it: the stash has the removal recorded in the index part of the stash. But the worktree part of the stash adds the file back, i.e., it does *not* have it removed. I don't know if this is intended behavior or a bug.

Comment: I think that fixed it @Hasturkun, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-apply the deletion using `git stash pop --index`, e.g.

```
$ git add foo bar
$ git commit -m 'initial'
[master (root-commit) 4bf33f4] initial
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bar
 create mode 100644 foo
$ git rm --cached bar
rm 'bar'
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 4bf33f4 initial
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git stash pop --index
Already up to date.
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    bar

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    bar

Dropped refs/stash@{0} (a998ca45e1230d40ac84403c9d84b5328e89b5bf)
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    bar

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    bar
```